# How to hide individual class in php while loop using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following `php` loop. It's showing for e.g. 4 Images.

```
while( $get_images_result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_images) ) {

    $image_id = (int) $get_images_result['p_image_id'];
    $p_large_image = htmlspecialchars( $get_images_result['p_large_image'] );
    $p_small_image = htmlspecialchars( $get_images_result['p_small_image'] );
    echo '<div class="col-md-3 existingImg">';
    echo '<div class="my_menu_image">';
    echo "<img src='".IMG_DIR."menu_images/$p_small_image' class='img-responsive' width='160' height='112' />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='p1' value='$p_large_image'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='p2' value='$mid'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='p3' value='$u_id'>";
    echo '<a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action menu_image_delete"></a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    $x++;
}
```

And you can see that there is a `menu_image_delete`  class in this line `echo '<a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action menu_image_delete"></a>';`

This `menu_image_delete` class is used for delete image. So once I delete each image it's successfully delete the image from Database and then I want to hide those selected image which I deleted. So that I am using following jQuery code but can't get it working :(

**JQuery Code :**

```
$('.menu_image_delete').click(function() {
    if ( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete this?') ) {
        var p1 = $('#p1').val();
        var p2 = $('#p2').val();
        var p3 = $('#p3').val();
        var param = 'delete_upload_image?p1='+p1+'&p2='+p2+'&p3='+p3;
        $.get(param);

        $('.existingImg').each(function() {
            $('.existingImg', $(this) ).hide();
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` in event handler which is the actual element event occurred on. Then traverse up to `existingImg` using `closest()`

Change

```
$('.existingImg').each(function() {
     $('.existingImg', $(this) ).hide();
});
```

To

```
$(this).closest('.existingImg').hide();
```

Note however that you should really only do this in success callback of `$.get` otherwise if the ajax request fails user will still see  element get hidden and assume all is well.

```
$.get(param, function(resp){
    // validate your response here and then hide image
});
```

Comment: Great, I used the parent() but it's still showing the SPACE after delete the image. BUT closest() is fine now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Because parent is `my_menu_image` not `existingImg`.